# JQuery drop down: positioning submenus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, submenu

I have a horizontal menu with vertical submenus in the traditional `<ul>` with `<ul>` manner.

I have created a simple JQuery code so that the submenu (the 2nd `<ul>`) appears on when the parent `<li>` is hovered over:

```
$('#menulist li').hover(
function() {
  $(this).find('ul').stop().fadeIn(200);
},
function () {
    $(this).find('ul').stop().fadeOut(200);
  }
);
```

This works fine but for one thing: All submenus fadein at the far left of the main menu so that they are not inline with their respective parent `<li>`s.

I believe this may have something to do with the CSS for the submenu using `position: absolute;`.

Does anyone know a way to perhaps amend my jQuery so that each submenu appears below its primary menu parent?

Thanks!

EDIT: added css

```
#menulist ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 10px; 
}


#menulist ul li ul{
        display:none;
        background-color:#FFF;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
    }
```

Comment: update your CSS code u did

Comment: update your CSS and HTML

Comment: Try Adding `padding-left` to `Zero` in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#menulist li').hover(function() {
     $(this).children('ul').stop().fadeIn(200);
},
function () {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().fadeOut(200);
  });
```

[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8smw/)

Comment: Thanks but that is missing the horizontal parent menu. - I have updated it with that css http://jsfiddle.net/MeltingDog/S8smw/3/